# VBA Update Link using UNC server path not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a macro to update linked data and do some other things as well to this data (filtering and sorting). The first thing it does is to update the linked data. The macro works using a mapped network drive. The macro does not work using UNC path. See code below for examples. If another user runs the macro with the mapped drive then they get asked where the file is. I'm trying to make things as simple as possible for them.

I have verified that the UNC path is correct. It works when i past it into explorer. The linked file under connections is linked using the mapped drive. I have tried to change it to a UNC path but it fails every time but freezing. I have let it sit more than 30 minutes. These two files are in different folders but in the same server. They are both in \server.server.company\officelocation\dept, just in different departments.

This works:

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:= _
"Y:\group\projects\subfolder\myexcelfile.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

This doesn't:

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:= _      "\\server.server.company\officelocation\dept\division\group\projects\subfolder\myexcelfile.xlsm", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

The error is

```
run-time error '1004': Method 'UpdateLink' of object' _Workbook' failed
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to manually update, for example, a single link using that path? Is the path accessible? Often it will not be for instance if you're not on the company VPN.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.updatelink "The name of the Microsoft Excel or DDE/OLE link to be updated, *as returned from the LinkSources method*"  Have you checked LinkSources to make sure you're using the correct name? LinkSources: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources

Comment: Yes i can manually update.

Comment: Think I finally figured it out. Some of the formulas used the mapped drive. When i switched it to UNC path then the macro works with UNC pathing.

Answer (score 0):

Think I finally figured it out. Some of the formulas used the mapped drive. When i switched it to UNC path then the macro works with UNC pathing.